# Unable to handle exception thrown from unmanaged/native code in managed code(c# wpf) such as out of memory exceptions globally

Tags: c#, exception, unmanaged

In my windows C#.net application, using some third party libraries which are of c++. and in few cases, I am unable to catch the exceptions thrown from those c++ libraries, I have tried all the below global exception handlers, but still unable to catch the exception.

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
- `OnUnobservedTaskException`
- `Current.DispatcherUnhandledException`
- `Dispatcher.UnhandledException`
- `Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter`
- `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException`

The application is getting crashed with out any information logged in file, but putting an entry in Event viewer with application error like below:

> Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.19041.789, time
> stamp: 0x82dc99a2
> Exception code: 0xc0000409

Also tried Marking the `RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)` in the AssmblyInfo file.
`<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />` in App.config file.
And Decorate the method with the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute

Also tried inline with the method which is calling third part method causing exception by placing Empty catch block

still unable to catch native exceptions.

I have so many calls for third party methods in many places, so I am not sure to handle all of them with Try catch. So I need a global handler to log the exception but not crash the application.

My requirement here is to catch the native exceptions globally and log to my log file with out adding entry in event viewer.

Comment: Managed handlers can only ever catch exceptions occurring on threads that run managed code. This places fundamental restrictions on what the exception handlers can do: you cannot, by any means, catch exceptions raised by unmanaged code on separate threads, for example. What's more, every new version of the runtime has made it more difficult, sometimes impossible, to handle "serious" unmanaged errors, which likely includes `0xc0000409` (`STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`). The path of least resistance is to sequester the calls in a separate process and use IPC to communicate with that process.